# Qt restart application whilst limiting instances to 1

Tags: c++, qt, restart

I'm using Qt5.6, I have code which will restart the application, but I also want to limit the number of instances.

The code that limits the instances works and so does the code which restarts the application, but with the limiting code enabled, the application will not restart, it closes down but I'm guessing that the restart is being blocked because at the time it tries to launch the new instance the PID of the original hasn't cleared.

Question is, how to achieve the result of closing the application, whilst limiting the total number of instances to 1 ?

If this hasn't been solved by tomorrow I will post the code for restarting and limiting instances, I don't have it with me at the moment.

Code to restart the application:

```
    qApp->quit();
    QProcess::startDetached(qApp->arguments()[0], qApp->arguments());
```

Comment: You could use a scheduled task or chron job to handle restarting the app.

Comment: I need to manage the restarting from within the application, thank you.

Comment: one solution is to invoke a script when restarting your app. the script monitors the current PID and when your app dies, it starts your app again. Otherwise, you can try just to reset your app without actually quit/start .. why do you need that anyways ? e.g. if you have certain settings that need to be read at the start, just try to reload those without restarting  ...

Comment: The application must restart itself? What if the application crashes?

Comment: I had thought of implementing the watchdog in Linux to monitor, so when the app. Stops kicking the watchdog it would restart it.

Comment: Could do with some help on how to utilise the watchdog in this way.

Comment: Maybe it would be sufficient to add a delay to the startup part where you check for other instances, to give the first instance time to shutdown.

Comment: @KarstenKoop, Thank you I will try this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just hints for the watchdog script:

1- you need to use QProcess::startDetached to run your script before quit your App. This will allow the script process to live after exiting your App.

```
QProcess::startDetached( "bash", QStringList() << "-c" << terminalCommand );
```

2- you need to pass the current App PID to your watchdog script via `terminalCommand`

to get the current App PID in Qt use

```
qApp->applicationPid();
```

3- in your watchdog script, have infinite loop that checks for the PID by doing

```
ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep $PID
```

once the PID is dieds, start your app again from your the watchdog script

Comment: Thank you will investigate when I'm at the system tomorrow